# Get - Append and find divs with class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, append, each

I got code:

```
      $.get( nextLink  , function( html ) {     
        $( "#item-cont" ).append($(html).find('#item-cont').html());  
      });
```

I want to get only div from item-con with class name .post (all div from this class name), now it getting all div in item-cont (i got deffrents div there).

How i can do that? I want to use each eg:

```
$( "#item-cont" ).append($(html).each('#item-cont .post').html());
```

but it's seems not work.

Comment: An `each` is not required (or desirable) when you can do it in a single operation. Answer added below covering your two possible requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you desired just the contents of the .post divs to be appended then you can do this in a single operation (uses an immediate child selector under the `.post` divs). An each is undesirable in jQuery if you can avoid it:

```
$.get(nextLink, function(html) {     
    $('#item-cont').append($('#item-cont div.post >', html));  
});
```

*If* you also wanted the .post divs themselves to be added,

```
$.get(nextLink, function(html) {     
    $('#item-cont').append($('#item-cont div.post', html));  
});
```

Comment: Yea that works too. Thanks, but i don't know why that work this option , i mean i don't understand. It's better than each i think than. Two quite good answers thank!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that I've understood what you're trying to do, you don't need to use `each()` in this case, just a modified selector. You also can append the nodes directly, so you can remove the call to `html()`. Try this:

```
$.get(nextLink, function(html) {     
    $('#item-cont').append($(html).find('#item-cont div.post'));  
});
```

Comment: With that i got only one div with class name .post from #item-cont . I want to get all div with this class name (10), witchout 3 (witchout that class on #item-cont).

Comment: Did you mean to put that additional `.html()` at the end? Not append the nodes?

Comment: It's append node but only one node from #item-cont , first node i think. It's dont add another 9 nodes.

Comment: The correctness of this answer depends on whether they wanted only the child nodes of the `.post` divs (Shaunak D's answer), or the `.post` divs themselves to be included too (your answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you have many`divs`to append, use

```
$.get(nextLink, function(html) {   
    $(html).find('#item-cont div.post').each(function(){  
        $('#item-cont').append($(this).html());  
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks thats work!:) I need only to add one more class to all div (i mean div on div agrr i do it self ;)

Comment: An `each` is not required (or desirable in jQuery) when you can do it in a single operation. Alternate answer added.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I had added 2nd Part of your answer first. But then for some reason I started getting downvotes. So, yes. Your's is the correct answer in this case.